# Difference in argument evaluation in Mathematica: Plot vs. PlotLog

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I can't seem to understand the difference between the behaviour of `Plot` and `PlotLog` (and other log-scale plotting functions) in Mathematica. Let's say I have this simple function:

```
f [a_] := Length[Range[0, a]]
```

now running `Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]` yields a correct graph, but when I try

```
PlotLog[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]
```

I get no output save the following error:

Range::range: "Range specification in Range[1,x] does not have appropriate bounds."

Looks like the evaluation of `x` is postponed which makes it impossible to create a list from `Range`, but why on Earth would it happen to log-scale plotting functions only and how do I handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlotLog` doesn't exists. If you use `LogPlot` it will work correctly.

In any case, you may have problems with that definition. I would recommend to define `f` like `f2[a_Real] := Length[Range[0, a]]` or `f3[a_?NumericQ] := Length[Range[0, a]]`so only numbers will be passed to Range.

For example, with your definition, this will fail:

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 1, 10}]
During evaluation of In[43]:= Range::range: Range specification in Range[0,x] does not have appropriate bounds. >>
18.
```

But defining a as NumericQ or Real, it will work.

```
NIntegrate[f2[x],{x,1,10}]
54.
```

Regards.

Comment: Okay, you got me, I don't know how I missed that. +1 for the argument type remark too, thanks!